# set-SPManagedAccount powershell command

Tags: powershell

The set-SPManagedAccount powershell command used as follows:

```
set-spmanagedaccount -identity "domain\validdomainaccount"
```

returns the following message:  The account domain\validdomainaccount was not found.

Can someone help me with this?  Is their something that needs to be done to the domain account before setting up as a managed account?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  Using new_spmanagedaccount is the appropriate command.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
new-spmanagedaccount -Credential $cred
```